# java.lang.illegalstateexception could not find method in a parent or ancestor context

Tags: android, kotlin, onclick

" I'm making a tictactoe app. im trying to make onClick over button but
it shows such error and the app is crashing."

here's my kotlin code

```
fun btnclick(view:View) {                               
        val btn=view as Button
        var cell = 0
        when (btn.id) {
            R.id.button1 -> cell = 1
            R.id.button2 -> cell = 2
            R.id.button3 -> cell = 3
            R.id.button4 -> cell = 4
            R.id.button5 -> cell = 5
            R.id.button6 -> cell = 6
            R.id.button7 -> cell = 7
            R.id.button8 -> cell = 8
            R.id.button9 -> cell = 9
        }
        playgame(cell, btn)
    }
```

here is the xml code

```
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="45pt"
                    android:layout_height="45pt"
                    android:onClick="btnclick"
                     />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="45pt"
                    android:layout_height="45pt"                    
                    android:onClick="btnclick"
                    android:textSize="45sp" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    android:layout_width="45pt"
                    android:onClick="btnclick"
                    android:textSize="45sp" />
...so on
```

[image: Logcat]

Comment: post your logcat

Comment: I don't know kotlin. However, the error message says it couldn't find an id `button5`. And your `id`s look like `android:id="@+id/button5"`. I'd be tempted to say `"button5" != "@+id/button5"`. Right?

Comment: nono  button5 matches with "@+id/button5". It shows some error regarding to View class.  but i dono what excatly it is

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot shows the click handler signature as taking a `Button` param.

The framework looks for a method that takes in a `View` param.

Change

```
fun btnclick(view:Button)
```

to

```
fun btnclick(view: View?)
```